# How to get top X records without overlap from multiple jobs?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Edit: if important SQL Server 2012

We have a table that has multiple jobs that process against it at once. It's the same query that is used in each job. How can we avoid locking and overlap in queries?

We have code that is in production but the person that made it is gone and there is no explanation in the query.

I think that the CTE (in the query) is important to this task but I have not been able to find an explanation as to why it might be. I haven't been able to search correctly because all the results I find are getting TOP X and not TOP X, without overlap, in multiple threads.

example table tmp1:

```
id | processed 
1  | 0
2  | 0
3  | 0
4  | 1
...
```

The table is big so I know that it takes a while to run and that is why we do it in batches.

The current query is like:

```
WITH tmpIDS AS (
  select top 100 * from tmp1
  where processed = 0
)
INSERT INTO #work (id)
select * from (
 update tmpIDS set processed = 1
output inserted.id
) a;
```

Everything after the query appears to either use the temp table #work or use the id and filter to one record on the original table.

The question we cannot answer is why this query is written this way. There are multiple jobs scheduled that run this query simultaneously (or near enough) and as we understand it they are not selecting the same TOP X records.

We expect this to cause the table to lock up and block each other but it is not, meaning it does work to some extent.

Even if there is something I can read to find an an explanation I will go read it but I haven't been able to find it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your code is doing is selecting the top 100 rows that haven't been processed, updating those rows to mark them as "processed", and then inserting the `ids` of the rows that were just updated into a temp table, presumably for processing.

This means that the first thing that happens is that the rows are marked as processed, so that another job won't come along and select them for processing while they are still being processed.

Comment: I understand that it is updating that way. I don't understand why the queries don't collide, why does the update happen and not interfere with other selects against the same table at the same time.

Comment: Your query doesn't have a NOLOCK hint, so unless the database is intentionally set to allow uncommitted reads, this update query will prevent any other query from accessing `tmpIDs` until it is done.